# ¿Hay alguna forma de ser prevenido sobre nuevas versiones cuando uso def en Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

El uso de `def` en Gradle es cómodo y práctico. Se define la versión y luego se usa esa variable al implementar las bibliotecas.

Por ejemplo, ahora estoy incluyendo Room en mi proyecto, se define `room_version` una sola vez, y en lo sub-siguiente se usa `$room_version` en todo:

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.4.2"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version"

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0-alpha01"
}
```

Es práctico. Pero veo un problema: **no soy advertido de nuevas versiones cuando uso una variable definida**.

Veamos este ejemplo:

```
def room_version = "2.4.1"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.1"
```

Si observan la captura de pantalla más abajo, Android Studio me advierte de que hay una nueva versión sólo en el segundo caso, porque ahí **puse la versión a mano**, pero en el primer caso no me lo advierte, porque **he usado la variable definida**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de usar la variable definida y ser advertido por Android cuando haya nuevas versiones.

Comment: Al ser un lenguaje compilado la variable de $room_version no es un string hasta la propia ejecución del programa y adquiera el valor de "2.4.1". Pero de la otra manera poniendolo a mano sin la variable definida el IDE es capaz de interpretar el string ya que este existe. Pero la variable necesita de la ejecución del programa para poder existir en ese entorno. Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que preguntas fue también una duda que me surgió ya que puede ser práctico declarar variables con las versiones y definiendo estas variables en las dependencias:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero esto no alertaba sobre si existía una versión nueva, lo cierto es que al **definir las variables y asignarlas a las dependencias actualmente la inspección LINT no soporta indicar una actualización, la única opción actualmente es definir la versión directamente en la dependencia**, de esta forma nos puede alertar si existe alguna actualización:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Actualmente las 2 buenas prácticas en cuanto a la definición de versiones en dependencias usando gradle serían:

**1)** Al especificar dependencias, no se deben usar números de versión dinámicos, como `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.+'`. ya que el uso de esta función puede causar actualizaciones de versión inesperadas y dificultad para resolver las diferencias de versión. Esto incluso aunque podemos declarar rangos de versiones: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html

**2)** Declarar directamente la versión en la dependencia, ya que en el caso de algunas IDE como Android Studio, la inspección de LINT de "Dependencia obsoleta de Gradle" busca usos de bibliotecas donde la versión que está utilizando no es la versión estable actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu excelente respuesta. Si he entendido bien, la respuesta sería que por el momento NO hay forma de ser prevenido usando variables definidas. Pero tu respuesta me genera una duda cuando dices: *Actualmente las 2 **buenas prácticas** en cuanto a la definición de versiones en dependencias usando gradle serían...* Si esas son las **buenas prácticas**, ¿en su documentación Android estaría sugiriendo **malas prácticas** dado que ellos usan mucho las versiones definidas en variables?

Comment: Hola, definitivamente no hay forma de verificar actualizaciones usando variables y como lo comentas, los ejemplos de Google se usa mucho el definir variables, pero en el caso de aplicaciones que en las que constantemente debemos actualizar sus bibliotecas como sugiere Google, no sería de mucha ayuda el usar variables para las versiones cuando trabajamos con una IDE como Android Studio o Intellij Idea. En cuanto al punto 1), aunque Google también nos muestra ejemplos con números de versión dinamicos, en la documentación puedes encontrar el mensajes que indica evitarlos: https://bit.ly/3IbLqhZ